# What software tool can I use for requirements management?

Tags: gratis, open-source, python, requirements-management

I'm looking for a free (no payment) and open-source tool that can help me keep track of requirements, with a parent-child hierarchy system included such that when a parent changes, a child is automatically marked as 'Needs Review'.

I would like for this tool to be incorporated / extended into an App that we write, which could be in Python or JavaScript or possibly another language if we like it.

Compatibility with version control storage of the requirements in Git/GitHub/GitLab is also beneficial.

For example, does anyone have experience in using 'Doorstop' and 'Mustard' to manage requirements? It would be great to hear any problems or unexpected benefits that have been experienced using these tools or any other such tools.

Cheers.

Comment: The only feature I'm looking for is no charge and open source and the parent-child hierachy style that I mentioned, I definitely am interested to know of anything that fits those criteria and I only know of a couple of these out there. I've edited to explain the free = no payment

Comment: s/feature/features

Comment: So a simple text editor would do? You can maintain parent-child relation by using text-indention. No pictures and no bold/italics etc, but you said not to need that. It's probably OK if it's only available for Solaris and there only in a terminal, right? And what does Python have to do with it, as you've used that tag? Plus, the second paragraph would be off-topic, as already stated.

Comment: Okk haha I mean technically yes I think we could use a simple text editor, but the boss wants a nice tool, which will integrate into / be used in conjuction with the web app we are writing, I think these tend to be more available in Python than JavaScript. I've expanded a bit more in the description

Comment: Sorry the text editor would need a teeny bit of code for the hireachy system, see above change

Comment: Ah, now we are getting somewhere :) Maybe you want to [edit] the question and incorporate what "niceties" the boss wants?

Comment: I have now elaborated to the full. All we want is on there. There should definitely be enough information on there. I am just looking for a tool that fits the above criteria.